# Some doubts related to Spring MVC model object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, model-view-controller, annotations

I am studying Spring MVC and I have some doubts related the concept of **model**.

So if I have a **controller** like this:

```
@Controller
public class RewardController {

    private RewardLookupService lookupService;

    @Autowired
    public RewardController(RewardLookupService svc) {
        this.lookupService = svc;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/reward/show")
    public String show(@RequestParam("id") long id, Model model) {
        Reward reward = lookupService.lookupReward(id);
        model.addAttribute(“reward”, reward);
        return “rewardView”;
    }
}
```

So, into this controller is definied the **show()** method that handle **HttpRequest** toward the **/reward/show** path and take 2 input parameters:

- **long id**: that is extract from the URL of the request, something like **/reward/show?id=1**
- The **Model model** object: I think that it contains the values to sharw with the view.

So this controller method perform a query on the DB and obtain a **Reward** object that put into the **Model** object.

So I can have this simple view named for example **rewardView.jsp**(the name and the path is automatically build by the Spring **view resolveréé) that show the content of the **Model** object:

```
<html>
    <head><title>Your Reward</title></head>

    <body>
        Amount=${reward.amount} <br/>
        Date=${reward.date} <br/>
        Account Number=${reward.account} <br/>
        Merchant Number=${reward.merchant}
    </body>
</html>
```

So my doubts are:

1. Is the **Model** object a specific implementation of a Java **Map** or is an object that wrap a Map? I think so because, as in a Map, I have a couple  where the KEY is the field name and the VALUE is its specific value to show in the view.
2. If my previous reasoning is correct the **addAttribute()** is a specific Spring method to put an element into this Map? why is not used directly the Map **put()** method?

Tnx

Comment: Yeah you're more or less correct, Model is an interface so it depends on the concrete implementation, but it is basically designed to allow you to add to an underlying map and access the overall model as a map

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Model is actually an interface, which declares the addAttribute method you mention.  In your Show method you are effectively using this interface to access a Map.

The "put" methods are not available through the Model interface, so you instead need to use addAttribute (which performs basic sanity checks on your key/value arguments and then "puts" them into the underlying map for you.

Answer (score 2):

[ExtendedModelMap](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework/spring/2.5.6/org/springframework/ui/ExtendedModelMap.java?av=f) is the implementation of **Model** object.

This class is extending ModelMap which itself is extending HashMap.

And **addAttribute** name is more meaningful as we are using it in servlet/web environment.

Answer (score 2):

The `model` (the M in MVC) is a `Map interface`, which allows for the complete abstraction of the view technology. You can integrate directly with template based rendering technologies such as JSP, Velocity and Freemarker, or directly generate XML, JSON, Atom, and many other types of content. The model Map is simply transformed into an appropriate format, such as JSP request attributes, a Velocity template model.